# How to choose an external powersource with electronic logic

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay, basic

I am a n00b in electronics (software developer)

I have 2 batteries bat1, bat2 (1.5 volts) available to me. I can only use one battery in my circuit. Let's say that if the  battery is put in a holder such as [image: battery holder] then it starts working

If I want to connect one battery (bat1) I just put that in. If I want to put the other battery (bat2), I swap the old one and put in the battery (bat2).

Now I want to do all of this but electronically. I really don't want to replace that battery with a robot :). Rather electronically start using the second power source.

**This question is not about choosing a backup power source. It is just about choosing what ever battery you want at command. Also This could be between 100 batteries.**

Makes sense ?

Comment: Welcome to the electronics community... Unfortunately, you aren't asking a question anyone can answer in its present form as it doesn't make any sense to hardware people. ASIC's are not "power sources". ASIC's do not "contain the battery" (with the exception of a few bleeding edge research prototypes). "Key"'s and "lock"'s don't make any sense without some information on the system context. If you revise your question, we'll be able to help you. Otherwise, I'm afraid the community will down-vote you to death (people are DV happy here compared to other SE's, FYI).

Comment: thank DrFriedParts. I tried to make the question clear. (the emphasis is on _tried_)

Comment: So you basically want something like a backup power system that can swap out one battery with the other?

Comment: Thank trygvis: I don't mind if the power source gets disconnected momentarily. I just want to be able to choose the battery. If you have 10 batteries, you can swap them out manually. I want to automate the process.

Comment: What will power your selector?

Comment: Chris, I imagine it would be powered independently.

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

What you are describing is called a an SPS (standby power source). You may be familiar with its counter-part the UPS (uninterruptible power source). Actually, what most companies sell as "UPS" for personal computers are actually SPS.

The core difference being that an SPS *switches* to a second power source if the primary is interrupted and the UPS keeps both available at all times so there is no switching delay.

## The physics

*That said*, WHY can't you use two batteries in your system? I think that is the bigger issue. A battery (like any source) provides two quantities: force (voltage) and flow (current) -- that's a simplification. It's like a water tank on a hill. The weight of the water (its mass in concert with gravity) creates pressure (force) on the downstream valves. When you open the faucet, the water (energy quantums) flow out (energy equating to the ability to do work).

## A possible solution

Sorry for all the physics, here's why that matters: The source (batteries) determine the force (voltage), but the load (thing you are trying to power) determines how much energy it needs (how much current flows).

With your batteries, any system that can tolerate one battery, can tolerate two so long as the voltage of the battery system remains the same. Connecting the batteries in parallel achieves this. If you use two batteries of the same chemistry, size, and age, simply connecting them in parallel will almost double the run-time compared to just a single one and you will not have to deal with any switching.

If you need to change the batteries without interrupting the system, just change them one at a time before the voltage of the parallel combination drops too low (say about 1.38V for EE91 alkaline chemistries). The load will transfer to the remaining battery once the second battery is removed. However, if you wait too long, the remaining single battery may not be able to support the system on its own in its sufficiently weakened state.

## The "simplest" SPS

If you Google for "USB Relay Board" you will find a tremendous number of vendors selling off-the-shelf modules that you can program over a USB serial link and will open and close one of many relays on command. You can use this implement your desired battery switching scheme (still not sure why you need to do this).

[image]

As I depicted, you bus the connection to the positive battery terminal of your key to all of one terminal of the relays. You connect each battery to a relay (at the other terminal of the relay) and you bus all of the battery negative terminals back to the negative terminal of your key.

You can add as many USB relay modules as you need. Just be careful with your software so that you implement break-before-make sequencing (disconnect, open, all of the relays before connecting the one you want to use).

## Welcome

I hope that covers the basics. If you have any follow-up questions, please ask and I'll elaborate. Cheers!

Comment: I cannot use two batteries, because they are infact discrete components. The batteries in question are housed in electronic keys, and the lock which they open don't have any other source than the keys them selves. You can see more about the system I am using here http://www.assacliq.com/components.htm

Comment: edited... try that.